# quartz.net Support with .Net Framework

Tags: .net, quartz.net

I have recently started working with quartz.net. I just want to know the   Quartz.net Support with .Net Framework 4.5 and above versions. I have searched in Google but didn't get any relevant answers.

Please advice me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least I can tell `Quartz` (NuGet Version 2.3.3) runs with `.NET 4.6`.